# Orchard programmatically purge cache

Tags: caching, orchardcms

I am caching something with:

```
var htmlHEAD = _cacheManager.Get(THE_CACHE_KEY, ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Monitor(_clock.When(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)));

            return getTenantSpecificHeadHTMLFromDB()
        });
```

However, I want to be able to hit a URL and purge the cache if a quick change is ever needed.

eg. this is in AdminController.

```
public ActionResult purgeCache() {
    _cacheMangager.PurgeCache(THE_CACHE_KEY); //this doesn't exist :(

    return Content("OK");
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't just monitor a time-based expiration, also monitor a named signal (inject `ISignals` and                     `ctx.Monitor(_signals.When("SomeUniqueKeyForYourExpirationSignal"));`), then trigger that signal whenever you want to purge the cache entry: `_signals.Trigger("SomeUniqueKeyForYourExpirationSignal");`

Comment: Interesting, but then wouldn't I lose the time based expiration? Ideally I want both, expires automatically after a set time AND can be purged manually.

Comment: Nope. If you set 2 signals to monitor, cache will get purged whenever either of those gets triggered. Bear in mind that the cache entry is not cleared right on the spot - it will be refreshed when you try to access it next time (ie. the lambda `ctx => ...` will get called again to refresh the entry).

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks you so much!